# Querying or interacting with Ethereum contracts using ABI

Tags: ethereum, abi, contract

I have the contracts ABI and I want to query the contract. I know there exists web3.js used for this purpose, however I haven't used it. I'd like to have the basic picture of how to interact with the deployed contract using its ABI.

1. Are there any other ways to use ABI and query the contract ?
2. I'm programming in C++/Qt and I'd like to query the contract using the ABI. Any idea ?

I also used metamask and myetherwallet for querying the contract, but it's not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ABI and a contract's address, you can execute the methods on it.

I'm not sure how you'd do that in C++ with existing C++ libraries.   However, in Web3.py (and similarly in Web3.js), at the most basic level, it's fairly straightfoward:

1. create a contract instance with the ABI and contract address
2. get an instance of the contract function you want to run
3. run the transaction on the contract method, with any parameters
4. wait for a transaction hash (tx_id)
5. use the tx_id to get a receipt.  The receipt has all of the goodies, like gas used, result data, etc.

In [Python using Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), this would look something like:

```
contract_instance = web3.eth.contract(address, abi)
contract_function = contract_instance.functions["contractMethodToRun"]
tx_hash = contract_function(*params).transact(tx_dict)
receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
```

For [Web3.js 1.0](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API), the steps are almost identical.

For C++, [here's a popular client](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/).  As you know by now, most work on Ethereum is done with Go, Node or Python.